# How can I deal with sequence item 0 error?

Tags: python, pandas

```
res = new.groupby(['id', 'survey_sequence', 'option_order'])['question_value'].agg('|'.join)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

"id" is object and the rest of the columns are integers. Why am I having this error?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) only accepts strings inside of it. You will have to change the type of the integers into string before joining them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `'str'.join()` takes strings, however you're passing an integer ID directly.
Instead, you have to convert the integer to a string, and then call .join. This can be achieved by utilising the astype function to convert the indexes to a string before passing them through `.join`:

````py
res = new.groupby(['id', 'survey_sequence', 'option_order'])['question_value'].astype(str).agg('|'.join)```
````

Comment: @TunahanAktaş if this worked, would you mind marking it as the correct answer?